# How to load library scripts in admin from plugins in noConflict wrapper?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, wp-enqueue-script, scripts

For my plugin I need to make a meta box for some custom fields in my CPT (`xyz`), and to organize the fields, I need to implement tabs. And I's taught to load jQuery/JavaScripts using `wp_enqueue_script()`, so from my plugin, I entered the following (with [Chip Bennett's suggestion](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41799/22728) in mind, I excluded `wp_register_script()` and used only the `wp_enqueue_script()` and *avoided* deregistering built-in scripts):

```
function my_scripts() {    

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-lib-scripts', plugins_url( '/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-for-tabs', plugins_url( '/js/jquery-ui.js', __FILE__ ) );
    //wp_enqueue_script( 'plugin-scripts', plugins_url( '/js/plugin-scripts.js', __FILE__ ) );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'plugin-style', plugins_url( 'plugin-style.css', __FILE__ ) );

}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts');
```

So the files are loading globally in admin panel.

Everything's fine, though I's full aware about the built-in WP admin scripts `jquery`, `jquery-ui-core`, and `jquery-ui-tabs`. But somehow my scripts are not conflicting, and is working with my tabs in my CPT's `post-new.php` (Add new) page; but is breaking the tabs in `post.php` (Edit screen of CPT `xyz`).

I am working on my dev. environment localhost using WAMP, and using WP 3.9.1, while I tried deactivating all other plugins and tried switching to default T14 theme.

Just found that, with my code the tabs are working in all pages, but if I activate any other plugin, even Akismet, it's **CONFLICTING**. I've learned about the [noConflict wrappers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers), but assumed they are only for custom scripts, but **how can I enqueue library scripts for my plugin in a noConflict wrapper?**

Comment: I'm not sure that'd work: noConflict is to avoid defining `$` because some other popular libraries also use `$` (e.g. mootools), it's not AFAIK intended to support entirely different copies of jQuery running in parallel. Do you really need that? Can you really not just use the provided jquery and jquery-ui-tabs? They're very recent, and jQuery is 1.11.1 so newer than you're loading.

Comment: If you really did need these versions your best bet would be to paste both scripts into a new file and wrap them in code that saves the old values of `$` and `jQuery`, loads your scripts (jQuery, UI and plugin) then restores the old versions. I can't promise that will completely not conflict (e.g. interfere with page-level events set up by the other copy) but I think it's your best hope.

Comment: I don't know WHY ON EARTH WITH ME, but I COULDN'T make it work ANYTIME doing `wp_enqueue_script('jquery')`. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm NOT actually Answering the question, I'm putting here, how I got my solution without being on that course:

First of all, I got the initial solution to the enqueue problem from [WPSE answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/59419/22728). It's working like a charm. But the problem of conflicting re-occurred when I tried embedding the Media Uploaded to a field with `wp_enqueue_media()`, it's not working even in that page the Featured Image jquery uploader was working.

I tried with deactivating all my plugins, and switched back to TwentyFourteen with `define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true)`. And with the suggestion of @G.M. I tried the following code provided by him:

```
function header_sent() { headers_sent() && die('Sent!'); }
add_action( 'init', 'header_sent' );
```

to check whether any header is sent already, but I got the green signal. Then with multiple try, and @Rup's comment, I enqueued all the latest jQuery things (jQ 1.11.1 and jQUI 1.10.4). But still the problem resides. But with these broad effort I at least found a hope that, my plugin is not conflicting with Akismet.

I revamped the `wp_enqueue_media()` with [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15344587/1743124). But when I activated WordPress SEO, though my plugin jQuery is working, but the WP SEO. So it's a clear conflict with the WordPress SEO.

Then I switched the meta box's priority from `'high'` to `'low'`$mdash; nothing happened. They something clicked my mind, and I eneuqued my scripts `in_footer` with:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-lib-scripts', plugins_url( '/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js', __FILE__ ), '', '', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-for-tabs', plugins_url( '/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js', __FILE__ ), '', '', true );
```

That's solved my problem here.
<sub>(But I actually don't know if the scripts conflict with any other plugin in future, then what would I do then :( )</sub>